Literature request: Jordan-Hölder property in exact categories
The Jordan-Hölder theorem says that any chain of subobjects of a finite length object can be refined to a composition series, and that any composition series has the same length. We say an exact category fulfills the Jordan-Hölder property when the Jordan-Hölder theorem holds.
It is very well-known that many abelian categories fulfill the Jordan-Hölder property, the category of finite length modules over some algebra, for example.
I'm looking for conditions for the Jordan-Hölder property to hold in exact  categories $\mathcal{E}$.
So far, I've found two conditions:

One is by Harusiha Enomoto relating Jordan-Hölder property to the existence of a basis of the Grothendieck group $K_0(\mathcal{E})$ of the exact category in
https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.05446, Theorem 4.12
The other condition is by Souheila Hassoun and Sunny Roy in https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03246, Theorem 6.1. They relate the Jordan-Hölder Property to the existence of pullbacks of admissible monos.

Are there any other known conditions?
I'm particularly interested in the following setting:

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra of infinite global dimension over some field $k$.
The exact category $\mathcal{E} \subset \operatorname{mod}A$ is an exact subcategory of finite dimensional $A$-modules.
$\mathcal{E}$ contains the projective modules.
$\mathcal{E}$ satisfies the two out of three property that is, whenever an exact sequence in $\text{mod}\,A$ contains two objects of $\mathcal{E}$, the third one also lies in $\mathcal{E}$.

But I'd like to collect any known conditions for exact categories.
Any help would be very appreciated!
